# UIPageViewController with unknown number of UIViewController instances

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want to create a `UIPageViewController` which use only one `UIViewController` but each new instance of it will hold different data each time. The `UIPageViewController` needs to hold 3 instances of the `UIViewController` each time [**previous**][**current**][**next**] and load the next or previous ones on the go. It's important to say that I don't use Storyboards.

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/miguelfermin/21c2332a8a1f164116f6fb618e719c22) link, but I have no idea how to do it because on the `setupPageController()` he is initializing the `UIPageViewController` with `UIViewControllers` which he created before (`pageViewController.setViewControllers`)

What is the correct and best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> The UIPageViewController needs to hold 3 instances

No it doesn’t. A page view controller has no fixed set of pages; it holds just one page. You do not need to plan ahead to create any other pages in advance.  That’s the whole point. When you are notified that the user wants the next or previous page, you decide right then what it will be and create it.  You can use any logic you like.

Comment: This example shows a typical architecture. I use different instances of the same view controller for each page. My logic in the data source methods is simple; yours might be very different. But the basic architecture is always like this. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p317pageControllerChild/ch19p626pageController/RootViewController.swift